# Crear de nuevo un «activity» con «onActivityResult»

Tags: java, android

Tengo dos (02) `activitys`. En el `activity` principal tengo creado un `startActivityForResult`. Es posible que cuando se dispare esta acción cree de nuevo mi `activity` principal con la orientación que yo le envié (vertical u horizontal).

Actualmente se pierde el cambio de orientación mostrando objetos ocultos de una vista vs. la otra ¿O hay otra manera de que cuando finalice la segunda actividad me recree de nuevo la primera actividad?

**Activity principal:**

```java
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult (requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Cambiaorientacion.CambiaOrientacion (this);
```

```java
Intent pref = new Intent (LogIn.this, Configuraciones.class);
startActivityForResult (pref, 0);
```

**`activity` Cambiar orientación:**

```java
public static void CambiaOrientacion (Activity a) {
  SharedPreferences prefs = a.getSharedPreferences ("Configuracion",
    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  int orientacion = prefs.getInt ("Orientacionpantalla", 0);

  if (orientacion == 0) {
    a.setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
  } else if (orientacion == 1) {
    a.setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
  } else if (orientacion == 2) {
    a.setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando usas `startActivityForResult (pref, 0);,` el segundo parámetro indica el `requestCode`, en este caso defines 0, por lo tanto en tu método `onActivityResult()` recibirías este valor al cerrar la segunda `activity` y regresar a la `actvivity` que realizo el `intent`.

Puedes definir que tu método `Cambiaorientacion()` reciba este valor para determinar el cambio de orientación:

```
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult (requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Cambiaorientacion.CambiaOrientacion (this, requestCode);
}
```

ahora si recibe el valor del request, podrías determinar la orientación:

```
public static void CambiaOrientacion (Activity a, int orientacion) {
  //SharedPreferences prefs = a.getSharedPreferences ("Configuracion", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  //int orientacion = prefs.getInt ("Orientacionpantalla", 0);

  if (orientacion == 0) {
    a.setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
  } else if (orientacion == 1) {
    a.setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
  } else if (orientacion == 2) {
    a.setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT);
  }
}
```